# If statement in setInterval only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so excuse me if I'm completely doing something I shouldn't be doing, and let me know so I can learn.

Anyway! The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var imgWidth = $(".window").width();
    var imgSize = $(".image_reel img").size();
    var imgReelWidth = imgWidth * imgSize;


    $(".image_reel").css({
        width: imgReelWidth});

    var num = 960;
    var numImgs = $('div.image_reel img').length;
    var currentSlide = 0;

    setInterval(function() {    
        currentSlide++;

        if (currentSlide != numImgs) {
            $(".image_reel").animate({
                left: -num
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            var setWidth = numImgs - 1;
            var newSlideNum = num * setWidth;
            $(".image_reel").animate({
                left: newSlideNum
            }, 1000);
            currentSlide = 0;    
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

What this code is supposed to be doing (or at least I thought it was...) is that after 2 seconds, it will loop through the if statement and check if the "current slide" is equal to the amount of images there are. Now I checked with the alert function to see if all the numbers are correct and they are, but for some reason, the slider is only working once, and that's it. Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Just make the proper variables global by: `window.numImgs = $('div.image_reel img').length;` and `window.currentSlide = 0;` otherwise as Blender also said, they're local variables of the anonymous `ready` function.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Them being local variables is helpful, not problematic (hurray closures!); them not being updated automatically may be problematic. (Or does it make a difference whether the enclosing function is anonymous or not?)

Comment: @Tomalak good point, as the `setInterval` function is inside the function where they're declared it should recognize those local variables just fine. Oh well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem:

```
var numImgs = $('div.image_reel img').length;
```

This holds the *number* of images at the moment it's called, not every time you call it. Replace `numImgs` with `$('div.image_reel img').length` in your code, and see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgWidth = $(".window").width();
    var imgSize = $(".image_reel img").size();

    $(".image_reel").css('width', imgWidth * imgSize);

    var num = 960;
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var setWidth = 0;
    var newSlideNum = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        currentSlide++;

        if (currentSlide < $('div.image_reel img').length) {
          $(".image_reel").animate({left: -num}, 1000);
        } else {
            setWidth = numImgs - 1;
            newSlideNum = num * setWidth;
            $(".image_reel").animate({left: newSlideNum}, 1000);
            currentSlide = 0;
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, but it didn't do the trick, it's still rotating once and it stops. The weird thing is, the count for the "CurrentSlide" is still going up, and when it hits the same amount, it rotating back to what should be the first slide, but because it isn't rotating, it's rotating to blank spots.

Comment: It might be a variable issue. You were declaring `newSlideNum` within the function, but that function is called multiple times. That means that those variables are lost. I re-declared them in the global scope, so see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help either. That stopped the slider from working all together.

Comment: Huh. Have you tried logging the values of the variables? If this won't work, there are *tons* of jQuery sliders available for use. Sorry :[

Comment: It's fine man, thanks though. I'm using this one because it's dynamic between an uploader that I created via php that the users can upload their own images too. Oh well, I guess back to the old drawing board. Thanks for your time!